# simplexml_load_file não funciona com arquivo XML grande - Request Time Out

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest, simplexml, simplexml-load-string

Estou utilizando o `simplexml_load_file` para fazer parse em um documento XML, porém, o arquivo possui mais de 100 mb e ao invés de carregar apenas parte das nodes, o que está acontecendo é que todo o documento está sendo carregado de uma vez, antes das nodes serem extraídas, e isso está dando um `TimeOut`, levando mais de 30 segundos para carregar a página, e no final dando erro.

O código é o seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Boutique</title>

 </head>
  <body>



<?php header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>



<!--   --><link rel="stylesheet" href="/va/artigos-complexos/afilio/afilio-vitrine.css" type="text/css" />
<div><p class="ofertasdotopovitrine">Conhe&ccedil;a nossas super ofertas!</p>
</div>
<div class="mainproductebayfloatright-bottom">

<?php

function parse($url, $offset = 1, $limit = -1)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $limitCriteria = '';
    if ($limit > 0) {
        $limitCriteria = 'and position() <= ' . ((int)$offset + (int)$limit + 1);
    }

    $products = array();
    $path = sprintf('//produto[position() >= %s %s]', (int)$offset, $limitCriteria);
    foreach($xml->xpath($path) as $product) {
        $products[] = array(
          'nome' => $product->nome,
          'preco_promocao' =>  $product->preco_promocao,
          'description' => $product->descricao,
          'link_imagem' =>  $product->link_imagem,
          'link_produto' =>  $product->link_produto,
          'preco_normal' =>  $product->preco_normal,
          'parcelas' =>  $product->parcelas,
          'vl_parcelas' =>  $product->vl_parcelas  
        );
    }
    return $products;
}

$products = parse('http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895987&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1010&format=XML', 5, 5);
?>


<?php
  foreach ($products as $product) {


  print '<div class="aroundebay"><div id="aroundebay2">';
    /* */
    print '<div class="titleebay"><a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="'. $product['link_produto'] . '">' . $product['nome'] . '"</a></div>';
    print '<div class="mainproduct"><a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="' . $product['link_produto'] . '"><img style="height:120px" src="' . $product['link_imagem'] . '"/><br/>';
    //print "De:;&nbspR$". $preco_normal . "<br/>";
    print '<span>Apenas&nbspR$' . $product['preco_promocao'] . '<br/></a></span></div>';
    //print "Em&nbsp" . $parcelas . "x de&nbsp:&nbspR$" . $vl_parcelas . "</a></span></div>";           
  print '</div></div>';
}


    ?>


</div>






 </body>
</html>
```

O css não tem relevância.

Se quiser trocar o URL do XML para um de um XML de tamanho pequeno, só para testar o código, utilize este:

```
http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895835&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1681&format=XML
```

Será que não seria possível carregar apenas os 10 primeiros Nodes, por exemplo, sem que para isso se tenha que carregar todo o documento?

Se alguém tiver uma solução que utiliza `jQuery`, eu também aceito.

Obrigado desde já.